# (iOS) NSMutableArray as property addObject does nothing

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a subclass of `UIViewController` with an `NSMutableArray` as a property to use as the data source for a `UITableView`.  I create an instance of the class in my storyboard.

I want to populate the array with the `addObject:` method but if I try, the array always returns `(null)`.

I read that `@synthesize` doesn't init the array and I might need to override `-init` and init the `NSMutableArray` there but `-init` never gets called.

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: What is the class that has the `NSMutableArray` property?  What is its superclass?  Are you creating the class instance in code or in a nib or storyboard?

Comment: It's a subclass of UIViewController linked to a storyboard view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create an instance of `NSMutableArray` and assign it to the property.

Since the object with the property is a `UIViewController` created in a storyboard, you can do it in a few different places.  You can override `initWithCoder:`, or `awakeFromNib`, or `viewDidLoad`.

If you override `initWithCoder:`, it is imperative that you call the `super` method.

If you do it in `viewDidLoad`, the array won't be created until the view is loaded, which doesn't have to happen right away.

I recommend doing it in `awakeFromNib`:

```
@synthesize myArray = _myArray;

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Another option is to just create the array lazily by overriding the getter method of the property:

```
@synthesize myArray = _myArray;

- (NSMutableArray *)myArray {
    if (!_myArray)
        _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _myArray;
}
```

If you do this, it is very important that you always access the array using the getter method (`self.myArray` or `[self myArray]`) and never by accessing the instance variable (`_myArray`) directly.

Comment: Thanks Rob, does look like -awakeFromNib is the best place as although -initWithCoder is called, if I implement it and do `if ([self = super] init])` none of my protocol methods get called for some reason. init in -awakeFromNib works great.

Comment: On a side note, xcode always adds the initWithNibName:bundle: method to all my uiviewcontroller subclasses but the method is never called in any of them. Why is it there and is it safe to remove it?

Comment: You can add initialization code to that method if you create your view controller programmatically.  Since you're creating your view controller in your storyboard, you can delete the dummy method. It's just part of the standard template Xcode uses for new subclasses of UIViewController.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what your code will need:

```
@interface BlahBlah : UIViewController
@property (...) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@end
```

At first, `*myArray` is just a pointer that's equal to nil. You can't use this as an array yet. It needs to be set to a valid NSMutableArray instance. You need to do this in the designated initializer:

```
@implementation BlahBlah

@synthesize myArray;

// -initWithNibName:bundle: is the designated initializer for UIViewController
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle];
    if (self) {
        myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // now you can add objects to myArray
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [myArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Note that you can't just override -init; you must override the designated initializer for your class. Figure out what subclass you are implementing, find out what its designated initializer is, override that (but call the superclass implementation as is often necessary), then init your properties.

Here's [Apple documentation regarding multiple/designated initializers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MultipleInitializers.html).

Comment: This is very common bug. Remember to initialize your arrays!

Comment: It is a subclass of UIViewController (adopting UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols). Xcode didn't create any init method in my class implementation. I tried overriding -init manually but it never gets called. Looking at some other UITableView subclasses in my project, some have -initWithNibName:bundle: so I trying copying that method but it never get called either. Where am I supposed to do custom inits in a UIViewController subclass?

Comment: From the UIViewController documentation, the designated initializer is `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle` . I updated this in my answer but I have not tested it.

Comment: I have put this in my implementation : `@implementation VideosTableViewController

@synthesize myVideos;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        myVideos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
     NSLog(@"init Called");
    return self;
}` But 'init called' never hits the log.

Comment: Unfortunately, designated or not, iOS does *not* call `initWithNibName:bundle:` when it is loading the object from a nib.  It calls `initWithCoder:`.

Comment: ...And tried replacing with your code (although the only difference seems to be the 'OrNil' on the var names) but the method is still never called.

Answer (score 0):

@synthesis neither do alloc. So alloc and init your array. Then it should work.

Comment: alloc and init that in the viewDidLoad